# how to migrate taxonomy images from drupal 5 to drupal 7

Tags: drupal, migration, taxonomy

### *how to migrate taxonomy images from drupal 5 to drupal 7*

I am migration a drupal 5 website, which is an old site, which contains alot of taxonomies and  vocabularies, which contains taxonomy images. I want to migrate them from drupal 5 to drupal 7 site.

Ideally I want it to be script based(can be MySQL or PHP) to migrate them. As there is a difference between the api of these major versions of drupal.

Currently I am migrating this site, by following this link
http://quicksketch.org/node/5739

All things are going smoothly, but i m kinda stuck in this situation. Please note that I have enabled taxonomy image module.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use the migrate module https://drupal.org/project/migrate

Also the  migrate_d2d module could be very helpful.